# How do I extract domains from email list in EmEditor or Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a list of emails and I would like help extracting just the domain names from the list of domains.

Sample Email list

```
email1@domain1.com
email2@domain2.com
email3@domain3.com
```

The preferred output I want is

```
domain1.com
domain2.com
domain3.com
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If an answer has helped you solve your problem feel free to mark the answer as accepted. You should also consider voting it up.

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+@`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
.+          # 1 or more any character but newline
@           # @ character
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you meant to show each email on its own line, like so:

```
Sample Email list
email1@domain1.com
email2@domain2.com
email3@domain3.com
```

If this isn't what your list looks like, it's going to get a little harder, but not much.

for each address, you've got three* parts: the username, the @-sign, and the domain.  the first and last will vary, but since they're always separated by the @, this is actually pretty easy:

in Notepad++ (or any regular expressions-aware text editor), you're going to search for an arbitrary string containing anything but an @, the @, and another arbitrary string: `.*@.*`

Since you want to return the second arbitrary string, put round brackets around that to save it: `.*@(.*)`
Now, in your "Replace" field, tell it to give back that saved string: `$1`

---

(So, what if your list really is all one line?  You'll need to search instead for "any character that isn't what separates the entries" rather than "any arbitrary character".  In regular expressions, we use square brackets to provide a list of "things to find", and put a caret (`^`) as the first one to say "things *not* to find".  So, for "any character but a space, tab, or new-line": `[^ \t\r\n]`.
Do it again to find the domain name.

```
[^ \t\r\n]+@([^ \t\r\n]+)
```

To *put* them all on separate lines when you're done, and remove all that extra whitespace while you're at it, (1) find all the whitespace after the bit you're going to save, so that you're finding the email address and the separator, but only keeping the domain; and (2) add a newline to your replacement string:

find: `[^ \r\n\t]+@([^ \r\n\t]+)[ \r\n\t]*`
replace: `$1\r\n`

I'm assuming, since you're using Notepad++, that you're on Windows. Your newline string may vary if you're on Mac or Linux.

A little more complicated, but not much.)

Comment: Thank you so much. I just implemented it and it worked very fine as expected. I really appreciate your support.